# Basic query about JavaScript and JSLint

Tags: javascript, jslint

I get a warning with the following function:

```
function getElement(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

> Problem at line 2 character 16: 'document' was used before it was
>   defined.

What does this mean?

Thanks.

Comment: You should tick "Assume browser" when running JSLint with code like this

Comment: If you really have such a function, then you should take a look at http://jquery.com, or http://www.prototypejs.org . Serious web developers do not write such low-level code these days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to assume a browser (`browser: true`).  Without that, it is treating `document` as a regular variable, which is clearly not defined.